# Is there a way to open the OpenFeint dashboard directly into the "Challenges" screen?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, openfeint

I'm looking for a way to open OpenFeint's dashboard view directly to the Challenges view.  There is a message that launches the dashboard, and one to display a challenge before it is sent:

```
[OpenFeint launchDashboard];
```

and

```
[OFChallengeService displaySendChallengeModal: @"challengeIDhere"
    challengeText: [NSString stringWithFormat: @ "my score is %d, can you beat it?", _score]
    challengeData: challengeData];
```

But I can't seem to find one that allows the user to view incoming challenges.

By the way, I'm using Cocos2d, so if there is a handy tutorial on creating a custom UI for challenges, I'd sure appreciate it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
[OpenFeint launchDashboardWithChallengesPage];
```

And btw, there are also:

- launchDashboardWithListLeaderboardsPage
- launchDashboardWithAchievementsPage
- launchDashboardWithFindFriendsPage
- launchDashboardWithWhosPlayingPage